# Relationship between two eigenfunctions of the time-independent Schrödinger Equation in one dimension?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

What is the relationship between two eigenfunctions of the time-independent Schrödinger Equation (in one spatial dimension) if they both have the same eigenvalue?

Comment: What kind of relationship are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a hamiltonian of the form
$$\hat H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$$
in one single spatial dimension, all the energy eigenvalues are non-degenerate, under suitable regularity conditions for $V(x)$. This means that if two eigenfunctions share the same eigenvalue, **they must be equal or, at most, differ by a phase**.

For a proof of this fact, and what sort of horribleness you must introduce into the potential to break this behaviour, try

> "Can degenerate bound states occur in one dimensional quantum mechanics?" Sayan Kar and Rajesh R. Parwani. [*Europhys. Lett.* **80** no. 3 (2007), p. 30004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1209/0295-5075/80/30004); [arXiv:0706.1135](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1135).

It's important to note that this is strictly a one-dimensional result, and fails to hold as soon as a second degree of freedom - be it spin or a second spatial dimension - is present; examples for that are trivial to construct.